# WCF, Silverlight: Is Request/Reply possible over PollingDuplexHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, pollingduplexhttpbinding

We have been using `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` for some time to do `Pub/Sub` messaging. We have methods that do not return results that allow clients to subscribe to some data feed then then the service pushes data back via `CallBack` contracts.

Just now we have been adding some `Request/Reply` methods to our `OperationContract`. As the clients are Silverlight 3 these methods are called using the `async Begin() End()` pattern. The problem is we cannot get this to work using `PollingDuplexHttpBinding`. We always get the following error (when client stack HTTP is used):

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

With browser stack we get `HTTP 500: Not Found.`

When switching to `BasicHttpBinding` the `Request/Reply` methods are called completely fine, but obviously `Pub/Sub` methods cannot be used with this binding.

We could use two seperate endpoints for each type of messaging, but would rather not and it seems odd to me that a binding would only support the `Pub/Sub` pattern (even though this is the motivation for `PollingDuplexHttpBinding`).

Could someone clear this up for me? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We never did get this to work. We use BasicHttpBinding for all of our Request/Reply operations between our Silverlight 4 apps and our WCF 4 services. These are all async method calls (have to be with Silverlight) to Per-Call services. For the couple of situations where we must do server push we have a Sessionful WCF service maintaining a PollingDuplexHttpBinding connection to the Silverlight client and we use Callback Contracts with One-Way methods to make calls.

Could never get Request/Reply operations to work with PollingDuplexHttpBinding, but never found an authority on the matter either...